# Socialtables API - Creating tables & populating them

Tags: social-tables

The [Socialtables API Docs](https://developer.socialtables.com/docs/api-usage/legacy-ids.html) don't seem to indicate whether or not I can create tables & populate them via the API. Is it possible, and does anyone know of any docs for formatting this kind of request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely - tables can be created for an extant event by making a `POST` request to our `/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/{team}/events/{event}/elements` endpoint. The request body should be a JSON-encoded array of floor element descriptors, which should each be composed as follows:

`{
  "random_id": (a UUID or other unique string),
  "event_id": (the ID of your event),
  "space_id": (the ID of your space),
  "pos_x": (the horizontal position of your table),
  "pos_y": (the vertical position of your table),
  "rotation": (the desired rotation of your table),
  "name": (the name that should correspond to your table, or an empty string),
  "width": (the width of the table, in inches),
  "length": (the length of the table, in inches),
  "radius": (the radius of your table, in inches, if circular),
  "layout": (specify 'table-rectangle-custom' or 'table-circle-custom' for rectangular or circular tables respectively)
}`.

The event and space ID can be obtained from your event's URI, or through the event and space listing endpoints respectively. For more information, including the endpoint for creating an event, see our full list of endpoints at https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console.